# Python compare two large file wordlists and print if match

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's say I have two large files. One is `md5_db.txt` and second is hash list `hash.txt`.

`md5_db.txt` contains hash and pass:

```
accfa1212a61b379ba0b009549113863:11150
12fd5b2b866858281404434d1b9a0284:111968
cd418b51dc28d28a239d0658cdd3bca6:111983
e0c10f451217b93f76c2654b2b729b85:111aaa
```

`hash.txt`

```
cd418b51dc28d28a239d0658cdd3bca6
e0c10f451217b93f76c2654b2b729b85
```

Now I want to compare them and find the hash and if it matches in both files, print the hash with password. I've been trying to find the most effective solution but I get close and then it doesn't work as wanted. The code I have is very simple, it doesn't work yet, unless I will split the hash from password, then it will find match. Basically in nutshell I need the script to grab the `hash.txt` and compare it to `md5_db.txt` and print if matched.

```
with open('md5_db.txt', 'r') as file1:
    with open('hash.txt', 'r') as file2:
        same = set(line.strip() for line in file1)
        same = "\n".join(same)

        for line in file2:
            word = line
            if word in same:
                print(word)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to load `md5_db.txt` into a dictionary:

```py
with open('md5_db.txt') as md5_db_file:
    md5_db = dict(line.strip().split(":", 1)
                  for line in md5_db_file
                  if line.strip())
```

And then it's easy to loop over `hash.txt` and print any matches:

```py
with open('hash.txt') as hash_file:
    for line in hash_file:
        h = line.strip()
        if h in md5_db:
            print(h, md5_db[h])
```

Comment: Nice, that's even easier than I expected it would be. Thanks for that

Comment: You got any idea why this would happen after loading the md5_db? `ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #2135 has length 3; 2 is required`

Comment: @uzdisral A password probably has the symbol `:` in it. Try replacing `.split(":")` with `.split(":", 1)` to only split on the first `:`.

Comment: that was it, appreciate it! @orlp

Comment: I came across another one, now loading a huge list. `ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #300637 has length 1; 2 is required` I think this time it's not the `:` as I tested it on site with multiple `:` in the file.

Answer (score 0):

Dictionary is the best way to lookup once you load the key and values in memory

Code:

```
dct = dict()
with open('md5_db.txt', 'r') as md5_file, open('hash.txt', 'r') as hash_file:
    for line in md5_file:
        hash_passw = line[:-1].split(':')
        dct[hash_passw[0]] = hash_passw[1]
    print(dct)
    for hash in hash_file:
        passw = dct.get(hash[:-1])
        if passw:
            print(hash[:-1], passw)
```

Output:

```
{'accfa1212a61b379ba0b009549113863': '11150', '12fd5b2b866858281404434d1b9a0284': '111968', 'cd418b51dc28d28a239d0658cdd3bca6': '111983', 'e0c10f451217b93f76c2654b2b729b85': '111aaa'}
cd418b51dc28d28a239d0658cdd3bca6 111983
e0c10f451217b93f76c2654b2b729b85 111aaa
```